# Why no template function makes more binary than template function

Tags: c++, template-function

See this simple program

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void foo(){ printf("%d",1); }
int main(){ foo(); }
```

I compile it with gcc 4.6.4  -std=c++0x -O2 -g -Wall  on linux.
And binary file  11`238 bytes.

But this code makes 11`150 bytes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

template< bool = false> void foo(){ printf("%d",1); }
int main(){ foo(); }
```

I also test with clang 3.3, results are 5684 bytes and 5636 bytes accordingly.

**Why no template version function makes more binary code ?**

Comment: That's 7 168 bytes and 7 168 in Visual Studio 2013 (version with default template value did not compiled, I had to provide it explicitly)

Comment: I will use VS 2014 :)

Comment: Obviously inlined version should occupy lesser space (there are no function call/parameters passing in this case). Have you tried "inline" for non-template version?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess, but:

In the first example, `foo` has external linkage and is not inline. The compiler will probably generate a non-inline version in case another translation unit uses it; and the linker might not remove it, leaving it taking up space in the executable.

In the second example, `foo` is a template, so the linker is more likely to be able to leave it out (since it needs to be able to deal with multiple definitions when the template is instantiated in multiple translation units).

You'd have to examine the binary to be sure of what's happening. Perhaps you'll see a difference if you declare the first one `static` or `inline`.

Comment: In the second version, `foo` is not inline.  It is a template, so the compiler knows that other translation units will also see the source (unlike the first case).  (Of course, inlining `foo` in either case is a very questionable decision on the part of the compiler.  Unless it is analyzing the `main` function, from which it can conclude that there are no other translation units.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: You're right; for some reason I thought that function templates were implicitly inline (rather than just behaving like inline functions as far as multiple definitions are concerned), and oversimplified my language a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no general answer here; it's very much up to the compiler implementation.

Also, the differences are very small so it's hard to even be sure it's a correct conclusion.

You should read the generated code; perhaps that can give you some clues as to where the bytes are shaved off.

Does it help if you make `foo()` in the non-template version `static`? Perhaps it's inlined in one case but not the other, and so on.

Comment: with static keyword  gcc : 1-version 11098,  2-version 11146. 
                     clang: 1-version 5636,  2-version 5584. 
I.e. after adding `static`, template version makes more binary code :)

Answer (score 0):

The output binary depends on the compiler's implementation. During compilation, it is going to generate table of symbols, which depends on the function names. Template function translates to a longer symbol name, and that increases the size of the binary.

You can see this by simply changing the function's name from `foo` to `foo1`, and that increases the binary by one byte.

After stripping symbols, the binaries have the same size

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dejovivl dejovivl 6288 Nov  5 13:00 a.out*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dejovivl dejovivl 6288 Nov  5 13:01 a.out*
```

---

to strip symbols, use [strip](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stripstrip) :

```
strip a.out
```